# Javascript Randomizer repeating all slices?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello & thanks for trying to help beforehand

I'm currently working on a page that has a Speechbubble in the center that is meant to give out Text from an Array. Those pieces of text are meant to be shown separately & Randomized, + none of them showing twice before the entire list is done.

Currently this needs to be known about my code:

```
function init(){ 
    document.querySelector('.speechbubble').innerHTML = chooser();
    setInterval(init, 3000);
}

function randomizer(array) {
  var copy = array.slice(0);
  return function() {
    if (copy.length < 1) { copy = array.slice(0); }
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var item = copy[index];
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    return item;
  };
}

var chooser = Randomizer(["i like birds", "i like turtles", "i like bugs", "i like oranges"]); 
window.onload=init;
```

I tested the function a lot via console and it does indeed work & give me out a different text every time. With the Interval set on Init I expected every 3 Seconds to jump from 1 textpiece to the next, which is does but then suddenly it also shows many text pieces in the beginning.

it's kinda hard to explain it but i'll try, first textpiece is fine, 3 sec later the next. 3 sec later the next and goes on for a bit then suddenly you see text appearing and vanishing between the 2 texts. This goes on some sort of loop until it takes several seconds for the next one to appear because it seems like texts that have already been used and sliced just spaam through the speechbubble before the next joke appears.

Does someone know how I can solve this to properly only show one joke at a time and properly jump to the next without the others appearing?

Comment: Please click `<>` and provide a [mcve]

Comment: What does `spaam through the speechbubble` mean?

Comment: @mplungjan the textpieces appear for 0.1 second and then jump to the next one and so on until the actual text appears. reminds me of one of those flipbooks kids play with

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the code for for example chooser - sounds like randomizer appends each text instead of selecting one

Comment: @mplungjan I did show you the code for the Randomizer right up there. My english isnt the best i assume so its hard for me to explain what is happening? I see one piece of text at a time but the more texts pass by the longer the dalys between the texts becomes & I see other texts passing by on my screen very rapidly until the actual joke appears. Chooser is just the name of the Array Variable where text is inside so jus imagine 

var chooser = Randomizer([i like birds, i like turtles, i like bugs, i like oranges)]
My randomizer is ment to slice & and show it, then next , until none is left.

Comment: Show the code. It is easier to understand than a comment trying to explain what it does  - I do not want to imagine anything, I want to click "run" and observe ;)

Comment: solved it. I kept opening the init function every 3 sec instead of having an own function for that, Thanks for nothing anyway :P

Comment: Show nothing, get nothing. How could we guess your issue when the rest of the code was giving you the problem?

Comment: @mplungjan I showed everything that was requird to help, I'm not even trying to come off like an asshole but if you were willing to help you would have seen the mistake in a minute with (i just boldly assume) coding know-how that I dont have yet since the mistake was super obvious =)

Comment: If `var chooser = randomizer` then why even have the chooser variable and not just call randomizer? IF your answer is because there is more to it..then that is the code people want to see.

Comment: I was willing. Your code was not helping guessing the issue. `document.querySelector('.speechbubble').innerHTML = chooser();` is not the same as `chooser=randomizer(somenotshownarray); =document.querySelector('.speechbubble').innerHTML = chooser() ` so that was one reason for me to not look any further.
I updated your code to show the new information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue:

```
function init(){ 
    ...
    setInterval(init, 3000);
}
```

Every time you call `init`, you create a **new** interval. Intervals are meant to be created once. In this specific case, you can replacing `setInterval` with `setTimeout`:

```
function init(){ 
    document.querySelector('.speechbubble').innerHTML = chooser();
    setTimeout(init, 3000);
}
```

And it will works as intended.
Or you can remove `setInterval` from `init` ad adding it to `window.onload`, to be sure it's called only once:

```
function init(){ 
    document.querySelector('.speechbubble').innerHTML = chooser();
}

window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(init, 3000);
}
```

For further information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Answer (score 0):

After creating a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your code and comments, here is a solution

```js
function init(){ 
    document.querySelector('.speechbubble').innerHTML = chooser();
}

function randomizer(array) {
  var copy = array.slice(0);
  return function() {
    if (copy.length < 1) { copy = array.slice(0); }
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var item = copy[index];
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    console.log(copy.length)
    return item;
  };
}

var tId, chooser = randomizer(["I like birds", "I like turtles", "I like bugs", "I like oranges"]); 
window.onload=function() { tId = setInterval(init, 3000); }
```

```html
<div class="speechbubble"></div>
```

This is a simpler solution:

```js
var tId, arr=["I like birds", "I like turtles", "I like bugs", "I like oranges"]; 

function init(){ 
  document.querySelector('.speechbubble').innerHTML = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
}

window.onload=function() {init(); tId = setInterval(init, 3000); }
```

```html
<div class="speechbubble"></div>
```